# Bootstrap 3.0: How to make vertical navbar dropdown not append to only last list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a panel layout that I've been throwing together and it has a fancy vertical navbar. I have it aligned correctly and everything and I have successfully been able to get a dropdown menu to appear in a vertical fashion, however, for some reason it is always appending to the last item on list. I can't understand why it is doing this.

I've posted all of my code below, and from previous research on the initial issue of just getting the menu to show up, I believe that my css is correct, so I'm wondering if it may be a javascript issue on the boostrap side, but I have no javascript currently being used with the side menu.

**CSS**

```
/************
* side navbar
*************/
#side-nav{
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.nav-stacked{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #3B3B3B;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
.nav-stacked > li > a > p{
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-stacked > li > a > span{
  font-size: 36px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-pills > li > a{
  border-radius: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.nav-pills > li.active > a{
  background: linear-gradient(#343434, #000000);
}
.nav-pills > li:not(.active) > a{
  background: linear-gradient(#4B4B4B, #3B3B3B);
  color : #e5e5e5;
}

.nav-pills > li:last-child:not(.active) > a{
  border-bottom: solid 1px #353535; 
}

.nav-pills > li:not(.active) > a:hover{
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #CACCCB);
  color : #333;
}

.nav-stacked > li+li{
  margin-top: 0;
}

#side-nav li.active.open, #side-nav li:not(.active).open{
    position: static;
}

#side-nav .dropdown-menu{
    overflow-x: visible;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: -92px 0 0 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.dropdown-toggle .glyphicon-chevron-right{
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 36px;
    left: 85%;
}
```

**html**

```
<nav id='side-nav' class='hidden-xs col-sm-2 col-md-1'>
  <ul class='nav nav-pills nav-stacked'>
    <li>
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span>
        <p>Driver</p>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>
      </a>
      <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
        <li><a href="/">EXPIRATIONS</a></li>
        <li><a class='clinic' href="#">CLINICS</a></li>
        <li><a class='drugTest' href="#">DRUG TESTING</a></li>
        <li><a href="/recruiting">RECRUITING</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/comcheck">
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'></span>
        <p>Comcheck</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/equipment">
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-wrench'></span>
        <p>Equipment</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I have a working fiddle to demonstrate what my issue is:

https://jsfiddle.net/ye1q4wfu/4/

All I want it to do is, when I click on the list item that has a dropdown. I want the dropdown to appear next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using a bit of JQuery, I think this will do the trick:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').each(function() {
    $(this).css('top', $(this).closest('li').css('top'));
});
```

You will also need to change one line of your CSS:

```
#side-nav .dropdown-menu{
    overflow-x: visible;
    width: 100% !important;
    //margin: -92px 0 0 100%; /* Removed */
    margin: 0 0 0 100%; /* Added */
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ye1q4wfu/9/)

Comment: Your answer is actually the most efficient and the only correct one. I just changed it to this on the margins `margin: -92px 0 0 100%;` and it lines up correctly no matter how many dropdowns I have. Wonderful thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! There may be an easier way to do it with CSS, but with such minimal JQuery, I don't see it being much less (if any) efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the top of dropdown to top: auto;

```
#side-nav .dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/fukujazuko/

My internet has some trouble with jsfiddle

Comment: I'm going to ask that before you post, you at least test it using the fiddle, it just helps me out in the long run as it does everyone else so we know what works better and what doesn't. Moving on... this aligns it to the bottom of the active dropdown menu, so it's close but not the solution.

Comment: i don't know if you tried that, because it's working at my end (i can't open jsfiddle) https://jsbin.com/fukujazuko/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS code that the sub-menu appears in front of the item.

```
#side-nav .dropdown-menu{
    overflow-x: visible;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: -290px 0 0 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer helps only in the instance that I would have one dropdown menu. This needs to be a global setting that works for any number of dropdown menus. Also it -276px not -290px because it is calculated from the individual heights of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the `clearfix` class to the `li` element in which your dropdown menu is. Then, these attributes to `dropdown-menu`

```
#side-nav .dropdown-menu {
  ...
  top: auto;
  float: right;
}
```

And added this css rule:

```
#side-nav .dropdown-toggle {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This is the complete snippet with the changes. When showing the code snippet, please, click on "Full page" to see the result.

```css
#side-nav{
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.nav-stacked{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background: #3B3B3B;
 overflow-x: visible;
 overflow-y: hidden;
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
   padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
.nav-stacked > li > a > p{
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-stacked > li > a > span{
  font-size: 36px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-pills > li > a{
  border-radius: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.nav-pills > li.active > a{
  background: linear-gradient(#343434, #000000);
}
.nav-pills > li:not(.active) > a{
  background: linear-gradient(#4B4B4B, #3B3B3B);
  color : #e5e5e5;
}

.nav-pills > li:last-child:not(.active) > a{
  border-bottom: solid 1px #353535; 
}

.nav-pills > li:not(.active) > a:hover{
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #CACCCB);
  color : #333;
}

.nav-stacked > li+li{
  margin-top: 0;
}

#side-nav li.active.open, #side-nav li:not(.active).open{
 position: static;
}

#side-nav .dropdown-menu{
 overflow-x: visible;
 width: 100% !important;
 margin: 0 0 0 100%;
 border-radius: 0;
    top: auto;
    float: right;
}

#side-nav .dropdown-toggle {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-toggle .glyphicon-chevron-right{
 font-size: 14px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 36px;
 left: 85%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav id='side-nav' class='hidden-xs col-sm-2 col-md-1'>
  <ul class='nav nav-pills nav-stacked'>
    
    <li class="clearfix"> <!-- ADDED THE CLEARFIX CLASS -->
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span>
        <p>Driver</p>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>
      </a>
      
      <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
        <li><a href="">EXPIRATIONS</a></li>
        <li><a class='clinic' href="#">CLINICS</a></li>
        <li><a class='drugTest' href="#">DRUG TESTING</a></li>
        <li><a href="/recruiting">RECRUITING</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <a href="/comcheck">
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'></span>
        <p>Comcheck</p>
      </a>
    </li>
 
    <li>
      <a href="/comcheck">
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-wrench'></span>
        <p>Equipment</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```